# How to store chunks of data in a variable in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi

I am sending Base64 string from server to client. On client side it is receiving portions of data one by one.

I want to store all data into one variable. How can i do that?

```
procedure TFrmClient.ClientSocketRead(Sender: TObject; Stream: TStream);
var
  zb_St: String;
begin
  Log(Sender, 'Data received from socket');
  with Stream as TMemoryStream do
  begin
    SetLength(zb_St, Size);
    Read(zb_St[1], Size);
  end;
  if Sender = ClientSocket then
    ClientBasefile.Lines.Add(zb_St);
end;
```

Comment: Wouldn't having a variable of a string type(in example a) in which you initialy asign '' and then just add the new string (a := a + zb_St;) work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know how to read a chunk into an `AnsiString`.  Simply append that to another `AnsiString` variable that exists outside of the event, eg:

```pascal
private
  F_zb_St: AnsiString; // <-- ADD THIS TO YOUR FORM CLASS

...

procedure TFrmClient.ClientSocketRead(Sender: TObject; Stream: TStream);
var
  zb_St: AnsiString;
begin
  Log(Sender, 'Data received from socket');
  with Stream do
  begin
    SetLength(zb_St, Size);
    Read(zb_St[1], Size);
  end;
  F_zb_St := F_zb_St + zb_St; // <-- ADD THIS
  // use F_zb_St and remove data from it as needed...
  // wait for the next event to add more data to it...
end;
```

Alternatively, you can get rid of the local `AnsiString` and just read into the Form's `AnsiString` directly, eg:

```pascal
private
  F_zb_St: AnsiString;

...

procedure TFrmClient.ClientSocketRead(Sender: TObject; Stream: TStream);
var
  OldLen: Integer;
begin
  Log(Sender, 'Data received from socket');
  OldLen := Length(F_zb_St);
  with Stream do
  begin
    SetLength(F_zb_St, OldLen + Size);
    Read(F_zb_St[1+OldLen], Size);
  end;
  // use F_zb_St and remove data from it as needed...
  // wait for the next event to add more data to it...
end;
```

---

On a side note: as you can see above, you don't need to typecast the `Stream` object to `TMemoryStream` just to access its `Size` and `Read()` members. They are both `public` in the `TStream` class, so you can remove the typecast.